# How to create a table with a fixed top row content and the rest of rows from database

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6

How to create a table view in swift with top row different than the rest of other rows.. Like if I open an app, the top row always shows information about exclusive food items from a set of restaurants and the rest of rows shows information about each restaurant  ( like name, address and menu and its exclusive food item) .

Comment: Basically the first row of a table should show preferred exclusive items from random restaurants menu.. Something like a Spotlight ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a table list in the app, the first row is fixed information, every other row comes from some database or server.

I suppose what you can do is at your

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return OBJ.count + 1
}
```

This would prepare the number of rows from your data source plus 1 for your first row. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you could do

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.row == 0{
  //DO YOUR FIRST ROW DATA PRESENTATION
 }else{
  //DO YOUR OTHER ROW DATA PRESENTATION
 }
        return UITableViewCell()
}
```

You could also potentially declare 2 segments, where the first segment has 1 row which is your static data and the second segment has your data.

Comment: I did a similar implementation ... I think it's close to my requirement. But can I control that first cell's content .. I mean if I create a class TableViewCell, can that be used while return ?

Comment: Yes you can. In the //DO YOUR FIRST ROW DATA PRESENTATION above, you can call whatever method that would generate labels or images and place them in the cell.